# An Odd Gedit Font Problem

Tags: fonts, gedit

For some reason I can not change my font type or colour in `Gedit`.

I tried going into `preference`, and choosing a `colour scheme` (the background changed only).

I was unable to even change the font type or size, I was able to choose one (I chose liberation Mono Regular 12) but it did not change the font it kept the default.

Nothing seems to be working.

Comment: font colors are specific to the color scheme in use, normal or otherwise. Text color  is set in that scheme's xml file. Typically a color is given a name, then that name used for something specific, ex. from Espresso Libre -, normal text color,    <color name="creme" value="#ffe6bb"/>  , then later,  <style name="text" foreground="creme" background="espresso-brown"/>  , the foreground determines text color, ect.

Answer (score 0):

To change the default font in `gedit`:

- Select `gedit` --- `Preferences` --- `Font & Colors`.
- Uncheck the box next to the phrase, `Use the system fixed-width font`.
- Click on the current `font name`.
- `gedit` will open a font-chooser window, allowing you to see available fonts and choose the one that you prefer*.
- After you have chosen a new font, use the slider under the list of fonts to set the default `font size`.
- Click `Select`, and then click `Close`.

[Source](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/index.html.en#configure-gedit)

Comment: Thank you Kyodake for some reason the fonts looked really similar to each other when I tried that before. It seems like I can change them now. Do you have any suggestions for the font colour?

Comment: Go to: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GtkSourceView/StyleSchemes